# Unusually long time in writing parquet files to Google Cloud

Tags: pyspark

I am using pyspark dataframe on dataproc cluster to generate features and writing parquet files as output to the Google Cloud Storage. There are two problems I am facing-

1. I have provided 22 executers, 3 cores per exec and ~13G RAM per executer. However only 10 executers are fired when I submit the jobs. The dataproc cluster contains 10 worker nodes and 8 cores per node and 30 GB ram per node.
2. When I write the individual feature files and record the total time, it is significantly lower then the time taken to write all the features together in a single file. I have tried changing the partitions but doesn't help either.

This is how I write the parquet file:

```
df.select([feature_lst]).write.parquet(gcs_path+outfile,mode='overwrite')
```

data size - 20M+ records, 30+ numerical features

Spark UI image:

[image]

The current stage is when I write all features together- significantly higher than all of previous stages combined.

If someone can provide any insight into the above two issues I will be grateful.

Comment: looks like a pretty small dataset ... why are you using spark for this? you could try lowering the ```spark.sql.shuffle.partitions``` to something like 8 as well as check for skewed data via size in stages tab (min, 25%, medium, 75%, max)

Comment: @thePurplePython- This is the output size generated. Raw data contains 60+ columns primarily strings. Doing Complex calculations like haversine distance, edit distance, substring matching etc on column pairs. In pandas it takes like forever. Anyways I plan to use >100M rows in future. 

I use repartition to 500 at the start of code. Without this I do not see any parallel computing happening.

Comment: Added "sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = -1")" to the script and works now.

Comment: interesting ... i use broadcasting all the time and haven't had the need to explicitly turn it off ... are you caching any objects?  this could result in your executor ram filling up and spilling to disk causing GC/hanging tasks

Comment: Not caching anything. Just one write operation at the end. Everything else lazy columnar transformation.

Comment: i have experienced random hanging tasks before and it was due to data skew from multiple window functions.  i turned those into pandas udfs and it then ran blazing fast lol